# AngularJS Service inside module not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to modularize my AngularJS application and put some services inside a Module. 
Everytime I try to reference my Service there is an error saying: 
Unknown provider: UtilsProvider <- Utils <- benutzerUebersichtController

My code is:

```js
var utils = angular.module('Utils',[]);
utils.service('UtilsService', function () {   
    this.CurrentUser = 'Hello World';
});


var verwaltungApp = angular.module('verwaltungApp', ['Utils'])


verwaltungApp.controller('benutzerUebersichtController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter','Utils', benutzerUebersichtController]);

function benutzerUebersichtController($scope, $http, UtilsService) {
$scope.Test = UtilsService.CurrentUser;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="verwaltungApp">
  <div ng-controller="benutzerUebersichtController">
    <span>{{Test}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You din't inject the service in your controller properly.

This :

```
verwaltungApp.controller('benutzerUebersichtController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter','Utils', benutzerUebersichtController]); 
function benutzerUebersichtController($scope, $http, UtilsService) {
    $scope.Test = UtilsService.CurrentUser;
};
```

should be:

```
verwaltungApp.controller('benutzerUebersichtController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter','UtilsService', benutzerUebersichtController]);

function benutzerUebersichtController($scope, $http,$filter, UtilsService) {
    $scope.Test = UtilsService.CurrentUser;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting this services in your controller:

```
 ['$scope', '$http', '$filter','Utils']);
```

But you are passing only these services:

```
function benutzerUebersichtController($scope, $http, UtilsService)
```

So your `UtilsService` is now your $filter inside your controller.

To correct you have to change to this.

```
function benutzerUebersichtController($scope, $http, $filter, UtilsService)
```

Comment: actually this was a second error i got, thank you! cant mark both sorry.